# Read Native format bcp data file

Tags: format, bcp

With the Unix shell script, I am doing a bcp out from a table in Server1 using NATIVE format to a file - XXXX.bcpdat, then bcp in the file to a table of same structure in Server2. 
The bcp command we have is 
bcp "$dbname".."$tablename" out XXXX.bcpdat -n 
bcp "$dbname".."$tablename" in XXXX.bcpdat -n -b10000

This bcp_out & bcp in works as expected from/into tables. 
But i want to da an urgent change here - 
**I want to get the total number of rows (a row may have 120 or 30 or 40 records)in the bcp data file (XXXX.bcpdat)**
But with the file in Native format i couldn differentiate each row & how its being separated. If i pass head -10 XXXX.bcpdat or tail -10 XXXX.bcpdat it prints everything in the file. "wc -l" or "awk" or "cut" is not helping me to get the count of rows from the file. There is no differentiation where a row ends like how it is in character load of bcp. It would really be great if someone help me at the earliest, how i can get the total number of rows (not records) that is in the bcpdat file. Thanks a loot in advance.